# Android Hello World Tutorial stops when tested

Tags: java, android, xml

I am up to the "Start Another Activity" section of the Android tutorial and it simply won't work when I install and test it.

It compiles fine but running it breaks after I click the send button.

I am using the command line tools on Ubuntu 12.04 and installing to a real device, my Galaxy S5.

I am aware of logcat but haven't been able to get it working, it either shows no output at all, or gives a massive spam of output I can't keep up with. I would happily provide logcat information if I could manage to isolate my app's output and cut through everything else.

I have seen a lot of similar questions on this which leads me to believe the tutorial isn't very well written.

Here is "MyActivity.java"

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    /** Called when the activity is first created */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is DisplayMessageActivity

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.example.myfirstapp.R;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get the message from intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        //Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        //Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MyActivity">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MyActivity"
            />
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT: Here is Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There was some code that I changed and took out as it said to add code in, but then would later show a "this is what your code should look like" and it was missing some of the original code. I also changed the manifest package names in the activities because at the beginning it uses `com.example.myfirstapp` but later uses `com.mycompany.myfirstapp`

Any help or advice on why this seemingly simple tutorial doesn't work is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Logcat output - (after pressing the send button)

```
I/Timeline( 3812): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.myfirstapp time:74636924
D/AndroidRuntime( 3812): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 3812
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:16)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3812):    ... 10 more
I/Process ( 3812): Sending signal. PID: 3812 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  871): Process com.example.myfirstapp (pid 3812)(adj 13) has died(104,205)
```

Comment: can you add styles.xml in values folder.

Comment: where is the listener for the first activity for some actions(send).

Comment: Post your stack trace..

Comment: @mustafasevgi I don't have a styles.xml in the values folder, just strings.xml

Comment: @Kervate Your code is look fine. you have issue about your package name.

Comment: You want to pass the user enterd string from MainActivity and display it into DisplayMessageActivity right?

Comment: @user3289108 Where You Look or found different Package name...it is same ...

Comment: @user3289108 That's right, at least that's the idea, I'm following the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage

Comment: @Kervate Where is your Listener or Calling Method sendMessage(View v)   This is wrong Syntax

Comment: @amitsharma I'm not entirely sure, I'm completely new to Android development. I was following the Android tutorial and that didn't seem to have anything like that.

Comment: @AlokNair How would I get a stack trace, I've looked and I'm unsure where I would put the exception handling as I have no idea what could be going wrong with the code, most of my programming experience is in shell scripting and C so this is all fairly alien to me.

Comment: @Kervate please try in manifest.xml 
android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
When i try this solution is work

Comment: ok i am posting a sample code

Comment: @Kervate post your logcat...we can get to know error form there.

Comment: @mustafasevgi I tried that but it's the exact same behaviour.

Comment: @AlokNair Do you have any advice for logcat? When I run the command it moves far too quickly and contains output from all other apps on the system, I tried a command to target just my package name but that returns nothing.

Comment: @Kervate http://www.javabeat.net/debug-android-application-logcat/ get yourself familiar to logcat from here, also there are plenty other links..just do a google

Comment: @AlokNair I've read through the link and I have been Googling but I just don't get it. From the link, it appears I have to write to the log myself? How would I log the error causing the program to crash when I don't know where it is happening or what it is?

Comment: @AlokNair I tried "adb -d logcat com.example.myfirstapp:F *:S" to try and filter fatal errors from my app but nothing is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code :

MainActivity.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    public void Go(View v)
    {
        Log.d("check", "Pressed");

        String value = et.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", value);
        startActivity(intent);
    }   
}
```

SecondActivity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView textv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_activity);

        String txt = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
        Log.d("check", "got : " +txt);

        textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textv.setText(txt);

    }

}
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="Go"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout/new_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity> // Registered the newly created activity

    </application>
```

Output :

[image]

[image]

Logcat :

[image]

**BY SEEING YOUR LOGCAT**, I got there is a problem in your Theme.

You didn't declared AppTheme in `AndroidManifest.xml file`

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by This Sample Code I have made For You.

mainactivity.xml Code

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/edtMessage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="message"
/>
<Button 
android:id="@+id/btnSend"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Send"
/>
```

MainActivity.class

Button btnSend;
  EditText edtMessage;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edtMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMessage);
    btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Message=edtMessage.getText().toString();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
        intent.putExtra("Message", Message);
        startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

second.xml

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/tviMessage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
/>
```

Second.class

TextView tviMessage;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    tviMessage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tviMessage);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     String message = extras.getString("Message");
    tviMessage.setText(message);
    }
```

Manifesto.xml

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".Second"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
   </activity>
```

Comment: This code does look promising but it changes my original quite a bit, notably taking things like the button presses away from the XML and into the Java, from what I've seen, the XML is the recommended method. How does this differ?

Comment: actuality you have not mention in your question what you actuality want ..Now You are saying These words ....

Answer (score -1):

By using logcat with this command:

```
adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep com.example.myfirstapp | cut -c10-15`
```

I was able to find the error causing the app to crash. It came from missing the line:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

In the Manifest.xml file. This is required by the Activity bar compatibility class. This part was completely overlooked in the tutorial, presumably because IDEs do this part automatically.

Thank you to everybody for their help and suggestions, it helped me keep looking and trying things until I finally found my solution.